# Formatting text in paragraphs

Tags: c#-4.0

Starting with unformatted paragraphs of text, I want to make the lines "Continuous" (that is, removing the new line characters). In the next paragraph, there are extra ("free") spaces in the first line from the text that came before.

Here is my code:

```
   private String FormateContent(String content)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = null;
        content = content.Replace(evaluationString, String.Empty);
        content = content.Trim().Trim('\r').Trim('\n').Trim('\t');



        if (content.Trim() != String.Empty)
        {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            String[] bodyLines = content.Split(new String[] { Environment.NewLine, "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            for (int i = 0; i < bodyLines.Length; i++)
            {
                if (bodyLines[i].Trim() != String.Empty)
                {
                    sb.Append(bodyLines[i]);
                }

            }
            content = sb.ToString();
            //  content = content.Split(new String[] { Environment.NewLine, "." }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToString();

        }

        return content;
    }
```

Comment: If reputation could be gained by the length of the title you would be the winner...

Comment: Can you add a sample of your input and your intended output?

Comment: I have rephrased the post (accurately, I hope), yet I do not understand what your question is.  Do you want to remove the extra spaces in the paragraphs after the first one?

Answer (score 0):

I think your primary problem is this code:

```
if (bodyLines[i].Trim() != String.Empty)
{
    sb.Append(bodyLines[i]);
}
```

You're testing the trimmed string, but then you add the un-trimmed string to the `StringBuilder`. I think what you want is:

```
string trimmedLine = bodyLines[i].Trim();
if (trimmedLine != string.Empty)
{
    sb.Append(trimmedLine);
}
```